# How to get the git description of the existing pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-api

How can get the description of my pull request in git with a command?

I can get only the commit ids of the PR

Comment: *Git* does not have anything called a "pull request". *Web-hosting services* like GitHub and Bitbucket have pull requests. The way you talk to the hosting service is up to the hosting service. Look to whichever service provider you are using to see (a) whether they offer a description at all and (b) if so, how to get it.

Comment: it is bitbucket. I want to fetch the pull request description and do some action.